# angular 2 unidirectional data flow and emitting events to parent

Tags: angular

I've read about the concept of unidirectional data flow in Angular 2, but I'm still unclear about several things:

1. If a change is detected in a component, will change detection run from the app root component down to all components, or just from the component where change was detected down to its children?
2. Lets say that an event has been emitted from some component to its parent, and that causes a change in one of the parent's properties. So a change detection cycle is run. The recently changed parent property may trigger a change in the child component, which triggers another change detection, and so on. So basically aren't we falling in a trap similar to the circular change detection problem that anguar 1.x suffered from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. yes, except components opt out by using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` (and no input value changed) or `ChangeDetectorRef.detach()`
2. In development mode Angular throws an exception. (Expression has changed since it has been checked)